# What bundle and entity_type do I use in field_create_instance to add a field to a taxonomy vocab?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a vocab with the machine_name = the_bundle. This is my call to field_create_instance:

```
field_create_instance(array(
  'field_name' => 'category',
  'label' => 'Some label',
  'required' => true,
  'widget' => array('type' => 'autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy'), // I've also tried options_buttons
  'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_vocabulary',
  'bundle' => 'the_bundle'
));
```

However when I use the drupal UI to manage the fields on the vocabulary, the instance does not exist. I have verified that the field I'm attempting to create an instance of does in fact exist. I'm also not getting any errors when I enable the module.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The taxonomy module doesn't define any bundle types for `taxonomy_vocabulary` (see [`taxonomy_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_entity_info/7)) so Drupal's entity/field system assigns it a default one with the same name as the entity type (`taxonomy_vocabulary`).

```
field_create_instance(array(
  'field_name' => 'category',
  'label' => 'Some label',
  'required' => true,
  'widget' => array('type' => 'autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy'), // I've also tried options_buttons
  'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_vocabulary',
  'bundle' => 'taxonomy_vocabulary'
));
```

I have to ask though, are you absolutely sure you want to add a field to the vocabulary rather than the term entity? I haven't come across many use cases where adding fields to the vocabulary itself is necessary. Drupal doesn't even have a UI to manage the fields (but I guess that could be why you're going this in code!)

Comment: I'm attempting to categorize 'the_bundle' by another taxonomy. Can one taxonomy term be direct children of multiple parent terms?

Comment: Also, setting entity_type and bundle to taxonomy_vocabulary didn't work.

Comment: How are you checking that it didn't work? Have you actually checked the `field_config_instance` table in the database to make sure it's not in there? As I mentioned Drupal doesn't provide any UI for fields on vocabularies so you're not likely to see any changes in the front end

Comment: I'm not sure about multiple parents for a single term, you can do it but I think they'll be limited to a single vocabulary

Comment: Ah, you are right, it appears that it is showing up in field_config_instance ... but you didn't mention that drupal doesn't provide a UI for fields on vocabularies .. ;)

Comment: I've also realized that I've had some lingo mix-ups. You're also correct in suggesting that I use the term rather than the vocab. That's what I wanted anyway ...

Comment: @Clive Your tip about `field_config_instance` helped me figure out why my code wasn't working. Thanks!